# Relative path in App.config is pointing at a different project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 project. Let's say it's at this directory:

```
C:\Project\Project A
```

I then copied and pasted it this new location:

```
C:\Project\Project B
```

In my App.config file, I have a relative path to a file in the project. However, in Project B, that relative path is pointing to Project A. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you not just modify the csproj file?

Comment: Can you show your App.Config file?

Answer (score 1):

By default your app will look for the config file in the same dir as its running from. But if you want to specify a path of the config file you can do so in the constructor like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", ConfigFilePath)
```